# Mule global configuration of defaultResponseTimeout not working if imported from another file

Tags: xml, mule, esb

I tried to set MQ timeout in one xml configuration file:

```
<configuration defaultResponseTimeout="${wmq.timeout}" doc:name="MQ Response Timeout Configuration" />
```

and then import it in another file:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:/mqConfiguration.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

but unfortunately it's not working in case of defaultResponseTimeout configuration. 
Another beans and configs are properly imported, only this one is not raised.

Is any way to fix this?